# Error handling on form submit

Tags: javascript

I have a form having some data

```
<form id="abc" method="POST" action="abc.html">
<input type="hidden" id="a" name="a" />
<input type="hidden" id="b" name="b" value="save"/>
</form>
```

and in js file i am submitting this form

```
document.getElementById("abc").submit();
```

What i want to do is if it throws any exception then an alert popup should open. Can anyone help?

Comment: What type of errors are u expecting?

Comment: Actully on form submit , from backend due to some special charecter , submit fails. am not sure how to treat on response failure condition.

Comment: Are you trying to say validation fails at client side?

Comment: Any non-jquery answers?